# CosmosDB logs appName (mongo API)

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using java MongoAPI for connection to Azure CosmosDB
Also I want to know if users are using my app to connect to my instance. I added appName parameter as connection options:

```
new com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions.Builder().applicationName("MyApp").build();
```

But I can't find where this information is stored on Azure side.
Where I can check this logs and clients applicationName?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Azure Cosmos DB diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging) to monitor your cosmos db account. Please configure the diagnostic log here on the portal.

[image]

You could send logs to azure storage, event hub or log analytics.

[image]

Surely,if your app hosted in Azure, you could check the log of your app on the `kudu`.

```
https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.com.
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where exactly should "MyApp" appear on diagnostic logs? On both DataPlaneRequest and MongoRequests logs I can't see application name

Comment: I have only next kind of logs after find operation: https://pastebin.com/zNBKuz8V
But no mention of 'MyApp' there.

Comment: @Limmy Have you check your application log on the kudu?

Comment: my app is not hosted in Azure, it is desktop application. I use only cosmosDB on Azure.